# Which one is more polite?

Tags: word-usage

Would "I deeply hope I could be recognized." be more polite than "I deeply hope I can be recognized."? Do the 2 sentences express similar meaning?

Comment: It is usually a good idea to wait for a few hours before accepting an answer. Please see this: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I deeply hope I could be recognized.

... sounds very odd any may be grammatically incorrect. If you want to talk about being recognized in the past, you should, instead, use:

> I deeply hope I was recognizable.

---

> I deeply hope I can be recognized.

... is grammatically correct. However, it can be improved:

> I deeply hope I'm recognizable. 
>   I deeply hope they recognize me.

Comment: Please do not leave comments asking the OP to accept your answer - the community finds it distasteful and we get a lot of complaints.